# Can we create multiple trigger under After_Insert Event in MySql?

Tags: mysql

I've a trigger in one of my table which is on `After Insert` Event, Now I need to create one more trigger on the same event `After Insert` but I'm unable to do that ! Is there any mysql limit or is there any way to create multiple trigger under `After Insert` event.

there is simple create trigger statement but I'm getting this : 
This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

Comment: Don't call it event. That is something else. You mean a trigger. And yes - there is only ONE `after update` and ONE `after insert` trigger for each table.

Comment: thank @juergen but I need to create 2 trigger under 'After Insert' what should I do ?

Comment: The error gives you the answer. You’re limited to one trigger per event. You can simply add the second code to the first trigger tho

Comment: You can put all code in the one trigger. Why two?

Comment: ohhkay and that will goes under multiple 
BEGIN, END Statement right?

Comment: No, when you insert a record in your table the trigger hits and in there you do multiple things. You can put all that in your trigger. No need to separate this

Comment: ohkay let me give it a try I think I can achieve this :) thanks @juergend

Comment: What version of MariaDB is this? It should be possible starting with MariaDB 10.2, but not with earlier versions.